# Cheating with the gp register on RISC-V - what could go wrong?

Tags: riscv

I absolutely have to pass an initialisation value to a dynamic library/module (everything is written in assembly) for some RISC-V code. The only way I seem to be able to do this is to use the `gp` register - and the code I am using runs and there are no crashes (yet). It is used to pass the value of a stack where a couple of initialisation values are stored.

```
 70         PUSH gp
 71         mv gp, s10
 72         call dlopen
 73         POP gp
```

(`PUSH` and `POP` are my main stack macros, `s10` points to the stack I am using to store values for initialisation).Everything runs on top of GNU libc/libdl.

I restore the value of `gp` as quickly as I can: everything says never change the value of this register - so what could go wrong, or if it works, can I just relax about it?

Comment: Why not use one of the `a` or `t` registers instead?

Comment: Because they are manipulated by the OS and so a value entered in the calling code isn’t preserved by the time we surface in the library itself.

Comment: If you have interrupts enabled, and the interrupts access global data using GP, things will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to write some library code that would allow access to read and write a memory location that held the value. So the writer (main executable) could write to the address and then the reader (library needing the address) reads it as required.